# Remove module of library from linking

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have made lib in Visual Studio. Lib have two modules: A.cpp and B.cpp.
In separate project i link to this library but i want to disable one of modules of this lib i.e B.cpp.

Comment: The question is a little hard to follow.  If `A.cpp` and `B.cpp` are compiled into one static library, you cannot only link against part of that library.  If that is the case, you will need to implement two static libraries, one for each module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not have to split up your lib.

The necessary contents of lib is only linked in if there are unresolved symbols remaining from your executable (exe/dll).
Unnecessary contents is generally speaking not linked in.

For example:

suppose your lib contains 2 obj-files ,**a.obj** from **a.cpp** and **b.obj** from **b.cpp**.

a.cpp contains among others the function `void a( int i )` which calls function `void b( int j ).`

b.cpp contains the function `void b( int j )`.

And suppose your executable contains in one of its source-files an implementation of a function

`void b( int k )`

and in some other piece of code you have a call to `void a( int )`.

When you link against the lib then linker at one stage is left with 1 unresolved symbol (that of the call to function `void a( int )`. It will search the libraries that you have specified for the first occurence of such a function-signature and it link in that part of that lib.
Since you executable code already contains an implementation of `void b( int )` it doesn't need to search any lib to resolve the call of it in **a.obj** ,so **b.obj** will not be linked in.

In summary (very simplified):

as long as you don't directly or indirectly call\use anything from b.obj ,it will not be linked in (unless you specify a lib as OBJ=YourLib.lib in your link cmd ,which pulls in the total library).

If you do directly or indirectly call\use something implemted in b.obj and you implement those symbols (functions or global variables) in your executable then either those parts of b.obj will not be linked in (in case of function-level linking specified) or you will get duplicate symbol link-errors if you forget something.

Answer (score 0):

Split the project into two, one of which contains `A.cpp` and the other containing `B.cpp`. Then if you need to link to both `.cpp` files you have to link to two `.lib` files. But if you want to link to just one, then you can do so.